# How can you call a variable in a method from within the object?

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm trying to learn OOP in javascript.

I made the following code that is supposed to return the time spent in a certain mailthread:

```
function mailThread(url) {
    this.timerIsOn = true;
    this.c = 0;
    this.url = url;
    this.timerCounter = function () {
        if(this.timerIsOn) { //doesnt get called??
            console.log('timerison');
            this.c = this.c + 1;
            console.log(this.c);
        } else {
            this.windowTimeOpen = this.c
        }
    }
    this.timerInterval = setInterval(this.timerCounter, 1000);
}

mailThread1 = new mailThread('test');
```

However this.timerIsOn seems to return undefined thus preventing the timer from running. What am I doing wrong here?

Also I tested this in the following Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B5vt5/

Comment: In your fiddle, why do you have `alersdsdt (this.timerIsOn);`?

Comment: sorry didn't save yet :S should be gone now

Comment: The problem is that the value of `this` changes when you pass the function reference to `setInterval`. If you declare `var self = this;` at the top of your function and continually use `self` instead of `this`, it should work: http://jsfiddle.net/B5vt5/2/

Comment: When your object ist supposed to be new'ed, then you should name it as an object with an uppercase letter by convention. It should be MailThread instead of mailThread to show that it must be new'ed instead of being a normal function you just call.

Comment: @Bunker I would also be careful using setInterval() as this is not accurate. it would be better to get the current epoch time when you set it up and count the time elapsed from that. it will always be accurate. More information here: http://www.epochconverter.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that within the scope of the function called timerCounter, "this" refers to the function itself. Do this:

```
function mailThread(url) {
    var self = this;
    self.timerIsOn = true;
    self.c = 0;
    self.url = url;
    self.timerCounter = function () {
    if (self.timerIsOn) { //Using self instead of this
        console.log('timerison');
        self.c=this.c+1;
        console.log(self.c);
    } else {
    self.windowTimeOpen = self.c
    }
    }
    self.timerInterval = setInterval(self.timerCounter,1000);
}

mailThread1 = new mailThread('test');
```

I recommend you look at [MDN introduction to OOP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)

Answer (score 2):

`this` isn't your object in the callback you give to `setTimeout`, but the global object (`window`). A solution is to save it in a variable :

```
var _this = this;
this.timerCounter = function () {
    if (_this.timerIsOn) { 
        console.log('timerison');
        _this.c++;
        console.log(_this.c);
    } else {
         _this.windowTimeOpen = _this.c
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.timerCounter` is a function.  When its called from `setTimeout` it's given the `window` context, so `this` is not what you think it is.

You either need to use `.bind` to set `this` to what you want.

```
this.timerInterval = setInterval(this.timerCounter.bind(this),1000);
```

Or, save `this` into a variable:

```
var that = this;
this.timerCounter = function () {
    if (that.timerIsOn) {
        // use that instead of this
    }
}

this.timerInterval = setInterval(this.timerCounter,1000);
```